# Can I use Z scores of my two dependent variables to compare difference between two independent variables?

Tags: experiment-design, z-score

I conducted an experiment to see which group is going to learn more (participants were learning chess tactics). I had three groups in the experiment, 2 experimental and a control group. Three tests were planned and conducted. First to see their baseline knowledge and **equalize the groups**. Second immediately after learning. Third - 2 weeks after learning. Tests were pretty much the same variation 30 question with 2 subscales, quite the same difficulty.

Unfortunately, the second test (immediately after learning) that I have used proved to be too hard, and couldn't show any significant difference in learning even compared to the control group. It could be because there was none, but also because the test was not discriminative enough.

So, for the third test, I adjusted the difficulty and made a test a little bit easier. Of course, all participants improved. Now I have a valid question how much of the progress is up to real learning and how much just because the test was easier.

What crossed my mind, and I am not sure whether it is statistically ok, is to standardize the scores of these three groups. So, the first score of all groups will have a Mean of Z scores around 0 as participants were distributed equally. But the second and the third tests will have different Mean of Z scores as some learning happened (if it did). Of course, Z would be calculated **using the M and SD of the whole sample**, as calculating Z from the Mean and SD of the specific groups wouldn't give any new information compared to the raw data.

Is my thinking ok? Am I allowed to do that - to use Z scores to compare different groups, not just individuals? I tried to explain my thinking to the professor, he says that it is not possible, but I can't really understand what I am missing.

Obviously, my statistics can be improved, but at least I would like to know why is there such a limit to using Z scores ...

Comment: It doesn't seem clear whether you're testing amount learned about chess or relative difficulties of tests. // Unless you know the population variances somehow, you will need to use t tests or ANOVAs, not z-tests.

Comment: Thanks. My intention was to eliminate the relative difficulties of tests originally.